# How to get out of the mode with many strands

Tags: modeling, 3d-view

So I was creating a plane and attempted to press control + r to create a loop cut and this happened: [image: I turned into like greater detail edit mode]

How can I go back into the normal mode where there is not that many strands?

Comment: "This happened" isn't a good way to describe the problem

Answer (score 1):

I'm not exactly sure what you're asking but from what i understand what you want is to turn off the SubSurf modifier in edit mode, go to the modifiers tab and press the button showed here : [image: SubSurf turn off in Edit Mode]